# SDWebImage not show placeholderImage

Tags: iphone, ios, sdwebimage

i have a image link people.avatarbig:http://ws.loc.sh/images/515b9f54e4b04a5a481030f9 
when you use browse to open it,you will see nothing,so SDWebImage should show placeholderImage but now it show nothing.my code :

```
 if(![GlobalVariable isBlankString:people.avatarbig])
        {
            [imageView1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:people.avatarbig]
                           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_user.png"]];

        }else{
            imageView1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_user.png"];
        }
```

why SDWebImage not show placeholderImage?

Answer (score 0):

i think this is a bug so you should modify the method :NS_INLINE UIImage *SDScaledImageForPath(NSString *path, NSObject *imageOrData)

the correct is :

```
if (image &&[[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
```